# Iframe height definition in IE 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a problem with resizing iframe content in IE7.
I have an external iframe

```
<IFRAME id=fl_game src="my_iframe_page" frameBorder=0   allowTransparency scrolling=no></IFRAME>
```

with width=100%, height=93%

and add my page into it. Here is a page body

```
<div id="container">
<div id="game-box">
<div id="flashcontent">

</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("<%=application.getContextPath()%>/flash/<%= request.getParameter(PARAM_GAME) %>/game.swf", "flashcontent", gameWidth, gameHeight, "10.1", "/flash/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params);
</script>
```

On my page I add resize events.

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", resizeGame, false);
    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeGame, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", resizeGame);
    window.attachEvent("onresize", resizeGame);
} else {
    window.onload = function() {resizeGame();};
    window.onresize = function() {resizeGame();}
}
```

Here is my resizeGame function

```
function resizeGame(isIEResize) {
    var flash = document.getElementById('flashcontent');
    var screen = screenSize();
    var width = screen.width;
    var height = screen.height;
    var left = 0;
    var top = 0;
    if (height * 1.5 >  width) {
        height = width / 1.5
    } else {
        width = height * 1.5;
    }
    flash.width = width;
    flash.height = height;
    document.getElementById('flashcontent').style.width = width + 'px';
    document.getElementById('flashcontent').style.height = height + 'px';
    document.getElementById('flashcontent').style.top = '50%';
    document.getElementById('flashcontent').style.left = '50%';
    if (width < screen.width) {
        left = (screen.width - width) / 2 + left;
    }
    if (height < screen.height) {
        top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
    }
    document.getElementById('game-box').style.top = top + 'px';
    document.getElementById('game-box').style.left = left + 'px';
}

function screenSize() {
    var w, h;
    w = (window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : (document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : document.body.offsetWidth));
    h = (window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : (document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.offsetHeight));
    return {width:w, height:h};
}
```

And here is a question:
In IE7 function screenSize() gives me wrong height on load. Under other browsers and IE>7 function screenSize() gives me correct height. That's why I can't resize my content properly.
And when I explicitly resize a window, function screenSize() starts to give correct height.
Here some screens before explicit resizing and after it.
[image: Screen before resizing]
[image: Screen after resizing]

screenSize() gives strange height ONLY in IE7.

I am ready to add any extra information to find a reason of this situation.
I hope someone can help me to find out how to define iframe height in IE7. Any help will be useful.

Comment: IE-7 is too old version of browser

Comment: I know but by customers don't. they have an old site which opens in IE7 compatibility mode even in IE11, so I have to support IE7 unfortunately

Comment: There is no reason to keep using IE7. As far as I am aware, you can still download IE8 from Microsoft if you're stuck with Windows XP. And if a site triggers IE7 mode in newer browsers, upgrade the site. Remove the `X-UA-Compatible` header.

Comment: I totally agree with you but I have no choice. And it's bad(